# Undisplayed characters on title on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, title, fonts

[This question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529119/prove-that-the-particular-function-3-is-continuous-at-%E2%88%921) has a title:

> Prove that the particular function $^3 +^$, is continuous at  = −1.

and some of the characters are not displayed properly.

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: Sony
- Device Model: E2312
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (4059386522)

Comment: Not really SE app problem, but the underlying system font on user's Android device. In other words, the font that's on the device doesn't support those unicode characters.

Comment: how to fix that?